# navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange event not getting triggered on Firefox 71 (Mac OS)

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, media, mediadevices

Before making a webrtc call I am latching into Bluetooth device, I place the call and during the call I switch off the Bluetooth device. Switching off the Bluetooth device is not triggering `ondevicechange` event.

Same scenario in chrome browser, `ondevicechange` event is triggered.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.ondevicechange = (e) => {
    //do your thing
  }
```

Any leads or anyone else facing the same issue with Firefox

Comment: Does it work in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, works fine with Chrome browser. I found out that, this event works in firefox only if media is flowing(which is not the case with chrome, it always triggers an device change event whenever device is added/removed)